# Combined WHERE clause for all INCLUDEs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
i want to perform this query in sequelize models:

SELECT Cou.country_id,cou.country_name, Sta.state_id, Sta.state_name, Dis.district_id,
Dis.district_name,Cit.city_id, Cit.city_name,Loc.location_id,Loc.location_name,Sub_Loc.sub_location_id,Sub_Loc.sub_location_name,Prop.property_id,Prop.property_name,Prop.hp_builders_id,
Bud.builders_id,Bud.builders_name
FROM hp_country Cou
INNER JOIN hp_state Sta ON Cou.country_id = Sta.hp_country_id
INNER JOIN hp_district Dis ON Sta.state_id = Dis.hp_state_id
INNER JOIN hp_city Cit ON Dis.district_id = Cit.hp_district_id
INNER JOIN hp_location Loc ON Cit.city_id = Loc.hp_city_id
INNER JOIN hp_sub_location Sub_Loc ON Loc.location_id = Sub_Loc.hp_location_id
INNER JOIN hp_property Prop ON Sub_Loc.sub_location_id=Prop.hp_sub_location_id
LEFT JOIN hp_builders Bud ON Prop.hp_builders_id=Bud.builders_id
where (Cou.country_status=1 AND Sta.state_status=1 AND Cou.country_id=1)
AND (Dis.district_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Cit.city_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Loc.location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Sub_Loc.sub_location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Prop.property_name LIKE '%ky%')
```

I tried to write in this manner but i did not achieved my target query :
 Included more nested models because of all are inner joins and i tried with required is true in include box.how to do [OR] condition for columns which is in different tables

```
hp_country.findAll({
    attributes: ['country_id', 'country_name'],
    where: {
        country_status: 1,
        country_id: 1
    },
    include: [{
        model: hp_state,
        attributes: ['state_id', 'state_name'],
        where: {
            state_status: 1,
          },
        include:[{
            model: hp_districts,
            attributes: ['district_id', 'district_name'],
            where: {
               district_status: 1
            },
            include:[{
                model: hp_city,
                attributes: ['city_id', 'city_name'],
                where: {
                    city_status: 1,
                    city_name :{
                        $like: '%ma%'
                    }
                },
                include:[{
                    model: hp_location,
                    attributes: ['location_id', 'location_name'],
                    where: {
                       location_status: 1,
                        location_name :{
                            $like: '%ma%'
                        }
                    },
                    include:[{
                        model: hp_sub_location,
                        attributes: ['sub_location_id', 'sub_location_name'],
                        where: {
                            sub_location_status: 1,
                            sub_location_name :{
                                $like: '%ma%'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }]

            }]
        }]
    }]
})
```

Comment: Have you defined associations between your tables?

Comment: yes ,already table exists and set a perfect relation ships also but i am confused at  this line in query  [AND (Dis.district_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Cit.city_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Loc.location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Sub_Loc.sub_location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Prop.property_name LIKE '%ky%')], how to perform or relations with different columns in different tables

Comment: Actually `seuqelize` doesn't allow to refer model instance, you have to do it using `Sequelize.col` or `Sequelize.literal`. And you don't have to go nested if you've defined all associations perfectly.

Comment: will u please give some example to perfom this query in  Sequelize.col or Sequelize.literal

Comment: Sure, I try to fix your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix your query, but didn't test it. If you face any problem just notify me:

```
hp_country.findAll({
        attributes: ['country_id', 'country_name'],
        where: {
            //main AND condition
            $and: [
                //first joint condition
                {
                    $and: [
                        { country_status: 1 },
                        { country_id: 1 },
                        Sequelize.literal("Sta.state_status = 1")   //I put 'state_status' here because it was a joint condition to be true
                    ],
                },
                //second joint condition
                {
                    $or: [
                        Sequelize.literal("Dis.district_name LIKE '%ky%'"),
                        Sequelize.literal("Cit.city_name LIKE '%ky%'"),
                        Sequelize.literal("Loc.location_name LIKE '%ky%' "),
                        Sequelize.literal("Sub_Loc.sub_location_name LIKE '%ky%'"),
                        Sequelize.literal("Prop.property_name LIKE '%ky%'")
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: hp_state,
                attributes: ['state_id', 'state_name']
            },
            {
                model: hp_districts,
                attributes: ['district_id', 'district_name']
            },
            {
                model: hp_city,
                attributes: ['city_id', 'city_name']
            },
            {
                model: hp_location,
                attributes: ['location_id', 'location_name']
            },
            {
                model: hp_sub_location,
                attributes: ['sub_location_id', 'sub_location_name']
            }
        ]
    })
```

Comment: thanq , but iam getting this error TypeError: sequelize.literal is not a function. I have a sequalize object also

Comment: hp_country.findAll({
        where: Sequelize.literal(),
        include: [
            {
                model: hp_state,
            }
        ]
    }) this is working

Comment: I think you have a reference with upper case `S` and used lower case `s`

Comment: see this one is also worked ,,when Sequelize in where condition its not working .. hp_country.findAll({
        where: Sequelize.literal("hp_states.state_name LIKE '%ka%'"),
        include: [
            {
                model: hp_state,
            }
        ]
    }). i got the ouput for this one

Comment: What query sequelize generates? Enable its logging and see the query in console.

Comment: thanq u man i am getting output slowly . i am checking step by step

Comment: my mistake is at  importing sequelize module from models folder to controllers folder .know also i am not imported its automatically getting sequelize variable in controller folder. i am getting correct query only in the console

Comment: working good but my problem is i am not import the sequelize variable in the controllers folder. but sequelize .literal () is working .my doubt is how its working . i connect total data base connections in models folder.

Comment: I have to use database connection sequelize  object or require('sequelize ')

Comment: require will also work, basically `literal` is in the utils library of seuqelize so just requiring the npm gives the access to all of its utility functions.

Comment: then is not getting any problem for connection pool  when one seuqelize is used for database connection and remaining for different uses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121030/discussion-between-shaharyar-and-simha-chalam).

Comment: everything is ok .but my last doubt is at district model